# Why can't I allow guest users to edit existing records in a custom object?

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites, guest-user, edit

I have a custom object named "Promotional Tokens", and need to allow guest users to edit a single field, on existing records in this object: Phone_Number__c. I've configured my site, and have a public URL, and have configured the profile for that site, but see no option to allow "edit" access on the guest user's profile.

Is this maybe a bug? I see lots of questions talking about read access, but I haven't had any trouble allowing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The policies on what permissions Guest Site Users may receive have evolved substantially over the last few years. The document [Guest User Security Policies and Timelines](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_guest_policies_timelines.htm&type=5) summarizes the current restrictions.

For your use case, the salient points are

> Guest users can’t have more than read access to data.

> Guest users can’t have the update or delete permissions on objects. Guest users can only update or delete records in System Mode.

If you really wish to do this - and it's a dangerous pattern! - you'll need to use automation in System Mode to do it.

Comment: I ended up having to do a VF page, with a custom controller `without sharing`. The [docs](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.sites_public_access_settings.htm&type=5#:~:text=You%20can%20also%20grant%20Read%2C%20Create%2C%20Edit%2C%20and%20Delete%20on%20all%20custom%20objects) do tell me that this is possible, though.